# Add background image to existing PDF in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am currently trying to add a background image to an existing PDF using NodeJS, but I cannot find the right tool to get the job done.
I have looked into pdf-lib (https://pdf-lib.js.org/), but couldn't find an option to embed background images within pdf-lib's documentation.

Is there a good library to get the job done?

Alternatively, it would also be acceptable to have another PDF as background for the existing PDF, instead of having a background image.